# Automated way to detect tests that can't fail, checked in to get by minmum code coverage?

Tags: testing, build-automation

I have a dev, that will get around our code coverage by writing tests that never fail.

The code is just atrocious, but the tests never catch it because they assert(true).

I code review, but I can't do everyones work for them, all the time. How do you get people like this motivated to make good software?

Is there a build plugin for detecting tests that can't fail?

C#, mbUnit tests.

Comment: Fire him! Why are you allowing a developer to sabotage your code!?

Comment: Just because you're doing code review doesn't mean you have to fix the code.  Do a review and when you find bugs, kick them back to the dev to fix.

Comment: Yes. Fire him or revert his code, that is unacceptable behavior.

Comment: I get to use one of my favorite quotes here: "There is rarely a good technological solution to a behavioral problem."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real motiviation comes from within.  Some people will game the system every chance they get sometimes for no other reason than they can.  Others do it simply because they are hacks.

That said, assuming your the manager, have a "come to jesus" meeting with the dev.  If that still doesn't work, there's always the door.

If you're not the manager, then take it up the proper channels.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've almost answered the question for yourself there. If you have someone work for you or with you (you're not clear no whether you are this dev's manager) then if they are not doing the job properly then surely there are procedures that are available to make it clear to this person that they are not producing work to an acceptable standard.

Is the dev new to TDD? Maybe they need some tuition on writing good tests etc. Otherwise they need a kick up the ass and have it stressed to them that the tests are as if not more important than the code he/she is producing.

Oh yeah, and on the plugin thing, forget that, just the same code reviewing you're doing should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should really specify the language / framework you're using.

In the simplest case, I suppose it should be easy to detect `assert(true)` strings with simple `grep`-ping.

Comment: I use assert(true) in catch blocks for exceptions that I expect to be thrown. Its my way of indicating to the the next poor sod who has to maintain my code that we expected the exception and I wasn't being stupid (not that the believe the later).

Answer (score 0):

You could always try a test run with garbage for the application configuration values.

Any tests that pass are suspect?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spending time on looking for tests that can't fail, how about extending the tests a bit - make the code fail in many ways. That would

- Show him how to write better tests
- Force him to fix his code, and prevent more bad code from being checked in

A piece of buggy code you have to use would be a good starting point -- you must be sure it works...

Answer (score 0):

Take the interface he's testing and reduce it to it's simplest form.  In other words, take the class/method signatures and only add the code needed to compile beyond that.  Run his tests against that.  Ask him why his tests are passing when the program does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Code Review, by two or more developers who are already test infected, is probably the best way to get the dev in question to see that automated unit testing is really not that difficult, nor unusual. Having two test infected developers on each review will reinforce the importance of quality unit tests to him.
Also, assigning him reviews of other developer's code which is well tested will help him learn how to unit test.

You should have a look at doing some [mutation testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing), to detect weak tests. [Nester](http://nester.sourceforge.net/), (the .Net equivalent of [Jester](http://jester.sourceforge.net/)) is one tool which you may find useful.

Please let us know how you go!

Update: I came across: ["Why do most developers not write unit tests, still?"](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2008/09/20/goodbye-mocks-farewell-stubs.aspx) and thought it would be good reading here  as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try to get him to write a failing test first. Try to get him into that habit. Often ppl new to unit tests have a hard time writing them.

Also there are some tools that can help you to "explore all possible code paths". I suggest you take a look at, **PEX** which will generate automated tests, and it will most likely break his code... While this might not be an optimal soultion, try to promoted the concept of a shared code base.

Get your devs to pair program, it is much harder to "be lazy" when you are working with someone else on the same function, and it will spread the code ownership around. You seem to be not doing this, since you talk about "**his**" code. It can be supprising how much you can get done if there are 2 persons working on the same job, It will increase the quality by a lot.

Also Unit-Tests are not the holy grail to eradicate all problems... They should be one of the tools you have at your disposal.

Whats your code cover requirement?

Comment: its a lot harder to really retort 2.5 years later. The ultimate goal was similar, require code coverage to increase or be overriden on check in at the build server, for promotion. Assert(true) doesn't really increase any code coverage, thus stopping the problem.

Comment: Hmmm... Didnt notice that... No clue why I landed on this one